# Elastic search multi language support

Tags: elasticsearch, multilingual

I want to store tweets of multiple languages in elastic-search and search them. I tried storing tweets with following mapping and could not able to search other than English. I'm sure the lang field is getting properly generated for each supported language by elastic-search. Can someone help me in understanding how to do multi-language search.

```
{
"mappings": {
    "tweet": {
        "_analyzer": { "path": "lang" },
        "_all": { "enabled": "false" },
        "properties": {
            "screename": {"type": "string", "store": "yes", index: "not_analyzed" },
            "id": {"type": "string", "store": "yes", index: "not_analyzed" },               
            "createdAt": {"type": "date", "store": "yes", "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" }
            "message": {
                "type": "multi_field",
                "fields": {
                    "message": { "type": "string", "index": "analyzed", "store": "yes" }
                    "default": {"type": "string", "index": "analyzed", "store": "yes", "analyzer": "simple" }
                }
            },
            "lang": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed", "store": "yes" }                
        }
    }
}
```

}

For information, I'm populating the language field as one of the following base on lang-detect google api, if api could not identify language then the lang field is empty.

`Arabic
Bulgarian
Simplified Chinese
Traditional Chinese
Czech
Dannish
Dutch
English
Finnish
French
German
Greek
Hindi
Hungarian
Indonesian
Italian
Norwegian
Persian
Portuguese
Romanian
Russian
Spanish
Swedish
Thai
Turkish`